# Inline-Block inside Inline-block Invisible Margin

Tags: html, css, font-size, display

See this pen for an example and one solution: https://codepen.io/MaxViewUp/pen/YrXzRG

I have an inline title that will have width acording to the text width, and i have an `:after` inside it (or an `div` if you want) with `inline-block` too and width of `70%`. I use inline-blocks because i have 3 variations of this title (left, right and center), so i just change the text direction to change the title.

**The problem:** The `inline-block` element is having an strange invisible "margin-top" from the text. I want to know why this is happening and an better solution. I think is something related to the `font-size` (bigger font size bigger spacing) but i'm not sure.

Solutions until now:

- `font-size: 0` - not an good solution because it mess the HTML;
- `display:block` or `float:left` on the `:after` -  not an good solution because text alignment will not affect it;

if anyone know exactly why this happens, please explain it.

CSS code:

```
.main-title {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 24px;
}
.main-title:after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 70%;
  height: 2px;
  background: green;
}
.main-title-wrapper {
  margin: 20px 0;
}
.main-title-wrapper.right {
  text-align: right;
}
.main-title-wrapper.center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

**NOTE**
I want to solve the problem but i really need is the reason this is happening (documentation, etc). Thanks for helping.

Comment: UPDATE: after years, looking back to my problem, i think now i would go with flex or inline-flex, it's way easier to use and way more predictable. Not sure if i could use it at that time (IE compatibility). Good to see your past self and see that you have improved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each inline or inline-block element on its own line (like your `:after`) element, will behave like a line of text, and is therefore subject to the line-height, vertical alignment and baseline of whatever font and font-size you've set on the parent (24px).

While it requires an extra element, your initial example solution of wrapping the text in its own element, applying a 0 font-size to parent, and applying the 24px font-size only to the text element (and therefore to that first line only), is the best solution if you don't want to resort to hacks such as negative margins or negative line-heights.

This is a summary of typographic CSS properties as they would apply to inline or inline-block elements: https://iamvdo.me/en/blog/css-font-metrics-line-height-and-vertical-align

Comment: Thanks for the well described answer (the best until now). Can you give an link for some documentation/article describing this?

Comment: This is a pretty exhaustive summary of typographic CSS properties as they would apply to inline or inline-block elements: https://iamvdo.me/en/blog/css-font-metrics-line-height-and-vertical-align

Comment: Thanks, its an good offline reading. I think the problem is solved, but i will wait a little  bit until an good solution to the problem (code alternative).

Answer (score 1):

```
.main-title{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 24px;
        &:after{
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            display: inline-block;
            width: 70%;
            height: 2px;
            background: green;
        }
}
```

How about using `position: relative` and `position:absolute`?

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QqbwbJ

Comment: Solves the problem but isn't an efficient solution (requires to change 2 elements to change direction)

Comment: And thanks for trying to solve the problem, but what i really want is the reason why this happens (documentation, etc)

Answer (score 1):

Use line-height to achieve expected result

https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/jGPEbX

```
.main-title{
    line-height: 7px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 24px;
}
```

Line height of the ::after pseudo-element will gets inherited from the main-title class div
Please check out this article with example for reference - http://www.testmycss.com/tips-and-tricks/css-before-pseudo-element-line-height/  and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height

Comment: This is the best solution until now

Comment: And thanks for trying to solve the problem, but what i really want is the reason why this happens (documentation, etc)

Comment: @Maxwells.c line-height explains it, the pseudo is written next line, both lines have the same line-height from the font-size value (it also explains why font-size:0; works). you can reduce a bit the gap setting vertical-align:top to the pseudo

Comment: sorry for the late reply @Maxwells.c , line height of the ::after pseudo-element will gets inherited from the main-title class div , nice article with example for reference - http://www.testmycss.com/tips-and-tricks/css-before-pseudo-element-line-height/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `inline-flex` with `flex-direction: column`

```css
.main-title {
 display: inline-flex;
 font-size: 24px;
 flex-direction: column;
}
.main-title:after {
 content: '';
 width: 70%;
 height: 2px;
 background: green;
}
.main-title.expected {
 font-size: 0;
}
.main-title.expected > div {
 font-size: 24px;
}

.main-title-wrapper {
 margin: 20px 0;
}

.main-title-wrapper.right {
  text-align: right;
}

.main-title-wrapper.right .main-title {
 align-items: flex-end;
}

.main-title-wrapper.center .main-title {
 align-items: center;;
}

.main-title-wrapper.center {
  text-align: center;
}

* {
 font-family: sans-serif;
 font-weight: 300;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
CSS problem:

<div class="main-title-wrapper">
 <div class="main-title">Normal</div>
</div>

<div class="main-title-wrapper">
 <div class="main-title">Normal - An Large text...</div>
</div>

<div class="main-title-wrapper right">
 <div class="main-title">Right - Lorem ipsum</div>
</div>

<div class="main-title-wrapper center">
 <div class="main-title">Center - Lorem ipsum</div>
</div>

<div class="main-title-wrapper">
 <div class="main-title expected">
  <div>This is what i expected:</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't solve the problem - the afters are not following the alignment

Comment: And thanks for trying to solve the problem, but what i really want is the reason why this happens (documentation, etc)

Comment: @Maxwells.c ah sorry missed the alignment part. You can address that using `align-items`. Updated my answer.

Comment: This EDIT solves the problem but the after doesn't follow the text alignment: requires 2 css rules.

Comment: @Maxwells.c you're welcome. It has something to do with the vertical alignment of `inline-block` items. You can use `vertical-align: top` to move that bar around, but then there is still a big space inside of `.main-title`. Not sure why.

Comment: @Maxwells.c ah gotcha, sorry I was just focused on the position of the pseudo element. updated the answer, and yeah requires a different rule for aligning the overall text and the pseudo element.

Answer (score 1):

Solution using relative positioning and giving greater spacing control: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oGXXmV

By definition of being `inline-block`, your `:after` pseudo-element is subject to the text sizing properties uniform to your title element. It is just on a new line, with the same line-height and other properties of the title text.

If you simply reduce the overall `line-height` of the title, as suggested by other answers, you are really just squishing two lines into the space of one line. No particular problem with this, but could have other unintended side effects depending.

This solution uses `em` so it will not change relative to your title even if you change the font size to something other than `24px` (highly recommend using `em` in general, much more accessible and adaptable).

```css
.main-title{
 display: inline-block;
 background: #fc0;
 height: 1em; /* tweak this value to control the overall height */
 font-size: 24px;
}
.main-title:after{
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 70%;
  height: 2px;
  background: green;
  position: relative;
  top: -.85em; /* tweak this value to control distance of line below text */
}
```

Comment: This is an great solution! I will use that on my code. I will not give this the accepted answer because i really wanted an explanation of the problem and Patrick gave an good explanation. Thanks for the good solution.